# Potential Dojo bug

Tags: jquery, dojo, html-entities

I've found a potential Dojo bug when I want to decode html entities. See my example:

```
require(["dojox/html/entities", "dojo/dom"], function(entity, dom){
    dom.byId('test'). innerHTML = entity.decode('&amp;euro;');
    dom.byId('test2').innerHTML = entity.decode('&euro;');
});
```

Both `divs` will show the euro sign. In my case I want to show the ampersand followed by 'euro;'. I know how I can accomplish this, but that's not my question. When I do the same 'decoding' in `jQuery` I get the expected result.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test3').html('&amp;euro;').val();
    $('#test4').html('&euro;').val();
});
```

The first case will show me '& euro;'(without the space ofcourse), the second '€'.

For me, the `jQuery` example is the expected behaviour. Am I right and may I open a `Dojo` ticket?

http://jsfiddle.net/NT8GX/

Comment: Have you opened a ticket? It seems it hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt No, haven't done that anymore.

Comment: @Р̀СТȢѸ́ФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ In case you didn't open a ticket, I opened one https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/18404#ticket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looked through the JavaScript code and it's indeed a bug. What happens is the following:

The decode-process uses two maps, one for regular HTML characters (like the `&amp;`) and one for latin characters (like `&euro;`). What happens when decoding is the [following](https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/master/html/entities.js#L192):

```js
// Apply the basic mappings.  HTML should always come first when decoding
// as well.
str = _applyDecodingMap(str, dhe.html);
str = _applyDecodingMap(str, dhe.latin);
```

Because it happens in two steps, it means that at the first step the `&amp;` is converted to `&` and in the second step `&euro;` is converted to the euro sign. The culprit here is the usage of these two maps, if they merge it into one it will not happen.

For example, if you decode `&amp;quot;` it will return the expected `&quot;`, because both entities are in the same map.

```js
console.log(entity.decode('&amp;quot;')); // Returns '&quot;'
```

If you're in need for a solution right now, you can fix it by yourself by merging the maps by yourself:

```js
var allEntities = entity.html.concat(entity.latin);
console.log(entity.decode('&amp;euro;')); // Returns '&euro;'
```

However, be aware that calling the `innerHTML` will also decode the entities, so then you will still see the euro sign.

---

So, to answer your question, you could indeed open a ticket. Be aware that this is part of the DojoX library (which means it's developed by other people than the Dojo core committers). The documentation says its still maintained, but I don't know how long it will take until there's looked at.

Comment: Ok! Already thought it had to be something like that(first encodes the ampersand and afterwards the whole 'word'). My experience with the Dojo community is that they are not willing to help you when something is deprecated. Eg. I've opened a few tickets for the `DataGrid`, but they won't help me because one of the founders of Dojo(SitePen's owner) has developed the `dGrid` and wants to make a profit. Ofcourse, I've dived into the defects myself and solved them(production environment), but it gives me a bleak feeling. Excuse me for my Dojo concerns ;)

Comment: This module isn't deprecated though, so they might look into it.